# How to make your own eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Who knows how to customize your own eclipse? I want to include some plugins and use it as bundled solution and not to install additional plugin when I want to use it on other machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to so called [Individual Source Bundle](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDEBuild/Individual_Source_Bundles), which you can build and create your own setup that will install your custom Eclipse bundle on desired machine.

Another solution would be just creating simple install/archive that will unpack `c:\eclipse\` to `c:\eclipse\` (or whatever) on target machine. This will work since Eclipse is not hardware dependent (but sure, it is OS dependent) because it's Java based.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've done in the past.

The first thing you have to do is a fresh install of eclipse, all the plugins you intend to use, and their configurations. After that just copy the eclipse folder AND the workspace/.metadata folder (this one could be an hidden folder) to the new machine.

Copying those folders to a new machine and running eclipse with the -clean flag (only needed the first time) seems to work fine so far.

I ran into some problems when trying to use 32bit eclipse in an 64bit environment, but I guess it's normal that it doesn't work. Also, this is not a cross-platform solution, i.e you cannot use your Mac installation of eclipse in Windows, or vice-versa.